# MIPS Print data in a recursive function

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am struggling with a problem in MIPS programming. I have the following recursive function:

> *F*(*n*) = 14*F*(*n* - 1) + 2*F*(*n* - 2) - 5*n*

I implemented it using a recursive function, it prints me the right answer.

My problem is: I want to print in console the sequence from *F*(0) and *F*(1), both are 1, to my *F*(*n*). I tried printing the register `$v0`, in which I store the final value, in each iteration of my function, but it prints out (for `5` for example): `6 71 6 986 6 71 13921`.

This is the code i inserted in my function for printing:

```
sw      $a0,var_curr
sw      $v0,print_curr
lw      $a0,print_curr
li      $v0,1
syscall
li      $v0,4
la      $a0,space
syscall
lw      $a0,var_curr
lw      $v0,print_curr
```

Where `var_curr` is the curent iteration; `print_curr` is the current value for printing, and `space` is the space between numbers.

Comment: Use QtSpim's single-step functionality to find out where any of the registers first get an unexpected value.

Comment: did that for 4 hours, can't figure it out.. I tried changing the position of that code in a done label, wich returns a value from stack, same thing, but it changes some of those numbers with 0

Comment: _"can't figure it out"_ What do you mean? Work out which values you should have on the stack and in the registers for each call for some input using pen and paper. Then single-step through your function and cross-check the actual register/memory values against the one you worked out earlier.

Comment: ps. for 3 it prints 6 71, wich is right, but for any other n greater than 3, it prints again 6 or 71 or 986, it depends on n

Comment: ok, i'll come with an update later on